# How Haskell's System.Console.GetOpt ReqArg Takes a 2 arity function as its constructors first argument?

Tags: haskell, getopt

I am still quite new to Haskell so forgive me if this is completely obvious and I am just not understanding correctly.

On Hackage [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html#t:ArgDescr) says that `System.Console.GetOpt ReqArg` takes a function of arity 1 e.g `(String -> a)` as the first argument to its constructor.

```
ReqArg (String -> a) String
```

In many of the examples that I have seen a 2 arity function is passed to this constructor.

Example from (https://wiki.haskell.org/High-level_option_handling_with_GetOpt):

```
data Options = Options  { optVerbose    :: Bool
                        , optInput      :: IO String
                        , optOutput     :: String -> IO ()
                        }

startOptions :: Options
startOptions = Options  { optVerbose    = False
                        , optInput      = getContents
                        , optOutput     = putStr
                        }

options :: [ OptDescr (Options -> IO Options) ]
options =
    [ Option "i" ["input"]
        (ReqArg
            (\arg opt -> return opt { optInput = readFile arg })
            "FILE")
        "Input file"

    , Option "o" ["output"]
        (ReqArg
            (\arg opt -> return opt { optOutput = writeFile arg })
            "FILE")
        "Output file"

    , Option "s" ["string"]
        (ReqArg
            (\arg opt -> return opt { optInput = return arg })
            "FILE")
        "Input string"

    , Option "v" ["verbose"]
        (NoArg
            (\opt -> return opt { optVerbose = True }))
        "Enable verbose messages"

    , Option "V" ["version"]
        (NoArg
            (\_ -> do
                hPutStrLn stderr "Version 0.01"
                exitWith ExitSuccess))
        "Print version"

    , Option "h" ["help"]
        (NoArg
            (\_ -> do
                prg <- getProgName
                hPutStrLn stderr (usageInfo prg options)
                exitWith ExitSuccess))
        "Show help"
    ]
```

So my question is do value constructors not really enforce the type when a function is used in its arguments or is there something else I am missing?

**Update:**

This is making more sense to me know. I believe there were a couple of factors that I was overlooking. First, as @CommuSoft mentioned, all functions really are a single arity in Haskell due to currying. Second, I didn't look closely enough at options which is not a function but a variable which is of type:

```
[ OptDescr (Options -> IO Options) ]
```

This type signature of options declares what the type of the type variable of ReqArg is as well as the other type constructors NoArg and OptArg (the latter not utilized in the example).

The single arity anonymous function passed to the NoArg ArgDescr constructor will essentially just be:

```
(Options -> IO Options)
```

E.g it will receive the Options instance record

Where as the 2 arity anonymous function passed to the ReqArg constructor will be:

```
(String -> Options -> IO Options)
```

And it will receive a string (the value someone entered at the command line) and the Options instance record.

Thanks to all for helping me think this through!

Answer (score 4):

The `->` you see in type signatures is, actually, a type too. And because of this, type variable `a` can be a function `b -> c`. In your example it is `Options -> IO Options`.

Answer (score 3):

`ReqArg` is not a function: it is a constructor. Now constructors are evidently functions as well. The signature of `ReqArg` is:

```
ReqArg :: (String -> a) -> String -> ArgDescr a
```

So you constructor returns an `ArgDescr a`.

Now a second aspect you have to notice is that `a` is in this case equivalent to `a = Options -> IO Options`, so that means the signature of your `ReqArg` constructor collapses to:

```
ReqArg :: (String -> (Options -> IO Options)) -> String -> ArgDescr (Options -> IO Options)
```

or less noisy:

```
ReqArg :: (String -> Options -> IO Options) -> String -> ArgDescr (Options -> IO Options)
```

(brackets removed)

So it is a function with "*arity*" 2 (note that strictly speaking in functional programming every function has (at least conceptually) arity 1). The point is that you generate out of the first argument a new function. But Haskells syntactical sugar allows to "define two arguments" at once.

## Explaining the documentation

That's the reason why in the documentation example, you need to use `foldr`:

```
return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)
```

Note this does not map on your (`Options -> IO Options`), in the example one uses `Options -> Options`.

The point is, in the documentation Haskell processes each command option individually. Initially you start with `defaultOptions`, and processing an option with `o` out of `n` results in a new `Option`, that you use as input for processing the next. After you completed the chain of elements, you return the final `Options` data.

## For your program

You make things a bit harder using an `IO` Monad: it was perhaps better to store a boolean whether you had to print the version, and if that was the case, do this in the `main`, or somewhere else. Nevertheless, you can achieve the same using [`foldlM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldlM) instead of `foldl`.